# A question on CSS selector syntax

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a question on CSS selector syntax.

What is the difference between the following two CSS selectors?

```
.myclass1 .myclass2 {
    color: black;
}

.myclass1.myclass2 {
    color: black;
}
```

Are they the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.myclass1 .myclass2`: select the element that has the class "myclass2" inside another element of class "myclass1";

`.myclass1.myclass2`: Select the element that have both class.

Answer (score 5):

`.myclass1 .myclass2` will match the inner DIV in

```
<div class="myclass1">
    <div class="myclass2"></div>
</div>
```

`.myclass1.myclass2` will match

```
<div class="myclass1 myclass2"></div>
```